# How to export an object from a file that contains a list of objects and import this same object in another file to be able to use it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How to **export an object** from a file that contains a **list of objects** and **import this same object** in another file to be able to use it?

// Example of Source File

```
const obj1 = {
  element1: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element2: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element3: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element4: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element5: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
}

const obj2 = {
  element1: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element2: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element3: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element4: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element5: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
}

export ????
```

// Example of Main File Importing from Source File

```
'use strict';
import ???

console.log(importedObject);
```

Comment: Is yours a NodeJS environment? Do you have a configured building process?

Comment: Yes, simple NodeJS with a source file serving a list of objects where another file will import just few objects from this source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ES6 Static Named [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) / [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) (ES6 Modules) syntax:

`./file-a.js`

```
const obj1 = {
  element1: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element2: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element3: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element4: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element5: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3}
}

const obj2 = {
  element1: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element2: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element3: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element4: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element5: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3}
}

export {obj1, obj2};
```

`./file-b.js`

```
import {obj1, obj2} from './file-a.js';

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: It gives me: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
I don't know why...

Comment: Yes, because ES6 modules support has been added just recently. You have two options: To add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file or to rename your files to use `.mjs` extension instead of `.js`. Other alternatives include transpiling your code (see BabelJS) or not using ES6 modules (not recommended). If the issue persist, try updating Node.

Comment: Added `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` and solved the problem! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CommonJS syntax:

For exporting:

```js
// objects.js

const obj1 = {...}

const obj2 = {...}

module.exports = { obj1, obj2 };
```

For importing the same:

```
// import file 

const {obj1, obj2} = require(./objects.js);
```

Mostly this is used in NodeJs backend structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
exports.obj1 = {
  element1: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element2: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element3: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element4: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element5: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3}
}

exports.obj2 = {
  element1: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element2: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element3: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element4: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3},
  element5: { property1: value1, property2: value2, property3: value3}
}
```

Your input syntax should work